# Listplot x axis - Using tranpose of two tables?

Tags: list-manipulation, plotting, ticks

I'm trying to augment the x axis of a listplot to fit the number of steps. Secondly, since there are a large number of steps (50), there will be 50 ticks which will make the graph messy. How do I get the x-axis to show ticks from 0 to 5 in steps of 1 instead of 0.1?

```
t1 = Table[
  FindRoot[({y2 + x2 } /. x2 -> pp ) == 10 , {y2, 5}], {pp, 0, 5,0.1}]
ListPlot[y2 /. t1]
```

[image]

```
xcoord = Transpose[{Table[ppp, {ppp, 0, 5}]}, {t1}]
ListPlot[y2 /. t1, Ticks -> {First /@ xcoord}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
t1 = Table[FindRoot[({y2 + x2} /. x2 -> pp) == 10, {y2, 5}], {pp, 0, 5,   0.1}]; 
ListPlot[(Last @@@ t1), Ticks -> {Range[0, 5, 1], Automatic}, DataRange -> {0, 5}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, if want to show part of the data (say, only 6 points) you can use

```
ListPlot[(Last @@@ t1)[[;; ;; 10]], Ticks -> {Range[0, 5, 1], Automatic}, DataRange -> {0, 5}]
```

to get

[image]